# I want to Sum user input and compare with if statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I am trying to see if $cvirtuals + $csports is less than $csuperdice
I have 3 inputs a,b, and c.
I wrote this code:

```
$cvirtuals = clean($_POST['cvirtuals']);
$ccolour = clean($_POST['ccolour']);
$csports = clean($_POST['csports']);

if (Math.abs($cvirtuals + $csports) < $csuperdice) {
$errmsg_arr[] = "Account is not balanced";
$errflag = true;
        }
else {
        die("Query failed");
    }

if($errflag) {
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    session_write_close();
    header("location: cashiers.php");
    exit();
}
```

When i run the above code, it returns query failed, even if the cvirtuals+csport is less than csuperdice. Please someone help me solve this problem.

Comment: `Math.abs(` remove `Math.` there

Comment: @Bert, your answer was highly helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't this because abs() always creates a 'positive value'.
So if your total of $cvirtuals + $csports, is negative (and so on lower) you expect it to be lower but because of the abs it will be a positive figure.

otherwise could you add some test data that goes in the variables ?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php